# ImportError: No module named 'zipFile'

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, importerror, python-zipfile

I am running python on windows in sublime text. When i wanted to work with the zipfile module I get this error ImportError: No module named 'ZipFile'. I tried changing the name to zipfile from Zipfile with no success. I looked at my pythonpath variable it does show the location of the lib folder where zipfile.py is located. I am unsure of what is going wrong. Any help or clue with what is going on is appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
import ZipFile
import StringIO

url = 'some_url'
z = ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()))
z.extractall()
```

Even running in python ide gives me the same error

Comment: The module's name is `zipfile`.

Comment: @MattDMo, I tried using zipfile too with no success

Comment: see @falstru's answer below - you need to call `zipfile.ZipFile(...)`

Comment: `from zipfile import ZipFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the module is [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). Also you need to use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). (There's no `StringIO` module in Python 3.x; I guesses you use Python 3 .x because of [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html))

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

url = 'some_url'
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()))
z.extractall()
```

Comment: btw, sublime text 3 uses python 3.3 only.

Comment: Thanks falsetru. I realized I made a mistake calling module name in the code instead of the import.

Comment: Yes you are correct @simonzack. Though I am using python 3.4 on Anaconda package for my venture into python :)

Comment: @Darshan Well it does work mostly with my python 3.4, so I think it'll work in your case too.